# Why can we consider only arbitrarily small epsilon in the definition of the limit of a sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

In the definition of the limit of a sequence I thought that we must consider all $\epsilon > 0$, but I learned that it suffices to let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary small positive number. That is we need only consider $\epsilon \in (0, x)$. I'm trying to found out how you can get this from the definition of the limit of a sequence.

Comment: Yes, it is enough that you consider all $\epsilon$ *sufficiently small*, though the definition may demand all $\epsilon$.

Comment: The def says "for all $\epsilon$", and "for all" means... *for all*. Thus, great and little ones are admitted. But we want to "stay closer" to the limit $L$, and this needs little neighbourhoods of it.

Comment: @астон-вілла-олоф-мэллбэрг That's what I don't understand, how do we go from the definition which demands all $\epsilon$ to the definition of $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.

Comment: @ArnautB By definition, if for some $\epsilon_0$, a certain $\delta$ works, then for every $\epsilon > \epsilon_0$, the same $\delta$ works. So if we fix an $\epsilon > L^x$, we can pick the same $\delta$ that we pick for some $\epsilon_0 < L^x$, and the definition will carry through. This also explains why it's enough to take sufficiently small $\epsilon$, since for large $\epsilon$ , the same $\delta$ works as for these $\epsilon$.

Comment: The definition of the limit $u_n\to u$ is that for every positive $\epsilon$ there exists $n_\epsilon$ such that $|u_n-u|\leqslant\epsilon$ for every $n\geqslant\epsilon$. If one only knows that $n_\epsilon$ exists for every $\epsilon\leqslant\alpha$, for some given positive $\alpha$, then $n_\epsilon=n_\alpha$ fits, for every $\epsilon>\alpha$, hence the full condition indeed holds automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this seems obvious now. From what @Did pointed out, if for any $\epsilon \in (0,x)$ we can show there exists $N_\epsilon$ such that $\forall n \ge N_\epsilon$

$$|a_n - L| < \epsilon$$

then for any $\epsilon' \ge \epsilon$ there exists $N_\epsilon$ such that $\forall n \ge N_\epsilon$

$$|a_n - L| < \epsilon \le \epsilon'$$

So we can conclude that for any $\beta > 0$ there exists a $N'$, (namely $N_\epsilon$), such that $\forall n \ge N'$

$$ |a_n - L| < \beta $$

Answer (score 1):

From Point Set Topology, we have the following definition of a limit point of a set:

$\zeta$ is a limit point of $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if every deleted neighbourhood of $\zeta$ contains at least one point of $S$. 
In symbols: 
$[N_\epsilon (\zeta)- \left\{ \zeta \right\}] \cap S \neq \phi$  $ \forall \epsilon$ $>$ $0$

Now, consider the range set of the function $f(x)$, i.e $R(f(x))$ with limit point $\zeta$ .
By now, I would like to introduce a theorem:

If $\zeta$ is a limit point of a set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then every nbd of $\zeta$ contains infinitely many points of $S$

[image: The theorem and its proof]

Let us now apply the notion to the range set of $f(x)$.
No matter how small the value of $\epsilon$ is, it still contains infinitely many values of the set. Thus, we can take arbitrarily small positive value of $\epsilon$. I hope, this answer will be helpful.