# Re-Why can we consider arbitrarily small epsilon in the definition of the limit of a sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My answer to the question goes as follows:

From Point Set Topology, we have the following definition of a limit point of a set:

$\zeta$ is a limit point of $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if every deleted neighbourhood of $\zeta$ contains at least one point of $S$. 
In symbols: 
$[N_\epsilon (\zeta)- \left\{ \zeta \right\}] \cap S \neq \phi$  $ \forall \epsilon$ $>$ $0$

Now, consider the range set of the function $f(x)$, i.e $R(f(x))$ with limit point $\zeta$ .
By now, I would like to introduce a theorem:

If $\zeta$ is a limit point of a set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then every nbd of $\zeta$ contains infinitely many points of $S$

[image: The theorem and its proof]

Let us now apply the notion to the range set of $f(x)$.
No matter how small the value of $\epsilon$ is, it still contains infinitely many values of the set. Thus, we can take arbitrarily small positive value of $\epsilon$.

[Original Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2434117/389992)

Is this justification enough, or am I missing something?

Comment: The short answer is that the limit is completely unrelated to any finite number of initial terms. Knowing the first one million terms of a sequence tells you absolutely nothing about whether the sequence converges or what its limit is if it does converge.

Comment: Yes, but is the answer rigorous?

Comment: What is the function $f$ here? I didn't see any function in the mentioned question. Are you confusing *limit of a sequence* with *limit of a function*? It's not clear to me at all what your argument has anything to do with limit of a sequence. You never mentioned the term "sequence" in your argument, except in the title.

Comment: Agree with @Krish . Moreover, if the function $f$ is constant, the range set of $f$ is a singleton, and possesses no limit points at all.

Comment: A sequence is basically a function from natural numbers to real set, isn't it?

Comment: Of course! But you need to say it explicitly that $f$ is the sequence, because in the mentioned question a completely different notation for sequence was used. (If you are asking a follow-up question with a given link, then it's for the best that you stick to the notation used in the previous question, or mentioned clearly what are new notations that you are using.) But then what will happen if the sequence is constant as mentioned by @grand_chat. What is the limit point in that case?

Comment: @grand_chat hats off! Great point. How do you guys come up with such concepts nice and smooth???

Comment: Alright, let's restrict ourselves to bijective funtions (sequence), then???

Comment: What if  $S$ the range set is finite? How can it contain infinitely many points?