# Equivalence definitions of limits of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of complex numbers, and let $a\in \mathbb{C}$. It is well-known that, if the following statement
$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:(n\geq N\implies |a_n-a|<\epsilon)$$
is satisfied, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=a$, as a definition. I have seen a lot of proofs that contains something with limits. My experience says that the following statements are equivalent, which I'd like to confirm,
$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:(n\geq N\implies |a_n-a|<\epsilon)\tag{a}$$
$$\forall K>0\forall \epsilon>0\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:(n\geq N\implies |a_n-a|<K\epsilon)\tag{b}$$
$$\exists\alpha>0\forall \epsilon\in (0,\alpha)\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:(n\geq N\implies |a_n-a|<\epsilon)\tag{c}$$

I have seen a lot of proofs that indirecly use $(b)\implies (a)$, and $(c)+(b)$ mixed implies $(a)$.

My short proof of equivalences is:

$(a)\implies (b)$: Assume $K>0$, then putting $\epsilon=K\epsilon'>0$, it implies $\epsilon'>0$.

$(b)\implies (a)$: If $K,\epsilon>0$, then put $\epsilon'=K\epsilon>0$.

$(a)\iff (c)$: It is obvious. (The $\impliedby$ can be seen in this [LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434117/why-can-we-consider-only-arbitrarily-small-epsilon-in-the-definition-of-the-limi)).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that all of these statements are equivalent. For $(a)\iff (c)$, you may want to put your reasoning into notation, although it is fairly obvious. To show complete equivalence, we can say something like $|a_n|-a<\epsilon<\alpha \leq E\in [\alpha,\infty)$, and we already have that this is true $\forall\epsilon \in (0,\alpha)$ and finally $\forall\epsilon' \in(0,\alpha) \cup [\alpha,\infty) \iff \forall \epsilon'>0$.

EDIT:
I wrote this before Hopeless added the link. For all interested, the link, as it addresses the specific question on $(a) \iff (c)$, has more succinct arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I did to $(a)\implies (c)$ is as follows: $\epsilon\in (0,\infty)=\bigcup_{\alpha\in (0,\infty)}(0,\alpha)$ which implies $\exists \alpha (0,\infty):\epsilon\in (0,\alpha)$. Therefore, we have $\forall \epsilon>0\implies \exists \alpha (0,\infty)\forall \epsilon\in (0,\alpha)$, something like that (I know it is an abuse of notation), if I am not mistaken. Does it look OK what I did?

Comment: Looks alright. You definitely have the idea.